# Multiple layouts in Ember 2

Tags: ember.js

I need implement next application structure with 3 routes:

```
localhost/users
localhost/posts
localhost/settings
```

'users' and 'posts' routes should have basic layout1 with main navbar.
'settings' route should have another layout2 with second navbar.

How can I implement multiple layouts approach with Ember > 2.12?

Can I set a layout name/path for each route or group of routes?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible recommended approaches to this problem. I've used both in different scenarios. You can either:

1. Use a component to encapsulate each navbar and then present them accordingly in each template
2. Set the [`templateName`](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_templateName) attribute of each route to use the correct template.

The component approach seems to be the easiest/most used in my experience. It also allows you to have differences within your base route template. e.g.:

`users.hbs`:

```
{{layout1}}
<h1>Users<h1>
...
```

`posts.hbs`:

```
{{layout1}}
<h1>Posts</h1>
...
```

While if you use the [`templateName`](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_templateName) approach, you are locked into using the same *exact* template. So, if you need any customization between any page that uses the same layout, you must use a subroute. e.g.:

`routes/users.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    templateName: 'layout1'
});
```

`routes/posts.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    templateName: 'layout1'
});
```

`templates/layout1.hbs`:

```
<nav>...</nav>
{{outlet}}
```

A third possible approach, though I don't necessarily recommend it, is to dynamically replace the navbars in the `application.hbs` template. The `application` controller/template have access to a special attribute called `currentPath`, which you can used to create two computed properties (`isLayout1` and `isLayout2`).

With that, this becomes a viable, though like I said, not necessarily recommended solution:

`application.hbs`:

```
{{#if isLayout1}}
    <nav>layout 1</nav>
{{else}}
    <nav>layout 2</nav>
{{/if}}
{{outlet}}
```